# How to add commit message using vim?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit

I want to add a commit message using vim (or nano, or any other text editor) rather than writing it in the command line using `git commit -m`.

How I can do this?

Comment: If you don't specify `-m <message>` on the command line, `git` will open an editor for your commit message.  See the `git-var` man page for some information on how to configure *which* editor will be used.

Comment: `git commit` without the `-m` will open your default editor for the commit message

Comment: I created a new test file. Did commit without the -m parameter and vim did appear. After I insert the text in vim, how do I save it to be the commit message?

Comment: Just save and exit with :wq

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This is mostly a question about using VIM, so let's to it.

First, you need to setup Git to use Vim as the editor, if that's not the default for you. You can do that by adding to the git config of your choice (none which is local, `--global` or `--system`):

`git config --global core.editor vim`

Then when you commit, you don't add the `-m` parameter, leave it blank:

`git commit
// or
git commit -a`

After that, you are in VIM, in escape mode. You then need to start insert mode to write. The simplest way is to type `i`, and a message will appear on the bottom (`-- INSERT --`). You are in insert mode and you can now type in your message.

After that, you must exit insert mode, and you do that by pressing `Esc` once. The `-- INSERT --` message on the bottom should vanish. You are now in escape mode again, and you must save and quit.

That is done by using the `:` key to enter command mode and typing the command `wq` or `x`, leaving you with either `:wq` or `:x` typed at the bottom.

`w` stands for write and `q` for quit, so `wq` is write and quit. `x` is an alias for `wq`.

After that you just press `Enter` and you're done, out of VIM.

If you have any doubts post a comment and I'll add it up.

Comment: I followed all the steps here. After I did :x, I got back to normal terminal window. How can I check that the file was committed with the message I typed in vim editor?

Comment: I am really sorry for not checking the comments section and taking so long. I bet you already know this by now, but for others who don't: just check the log with `git log`. This opens the git log for all commits using `less`. You can navigate using up and down arrows or spacebar, and quit by pressing the letter `q`.

Comment: I changed "vim" to "nvim" and it worked like a charm too. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

When using

```
git commit
```

a vim console will open automatically, when using the 'normal' settings.

In the vim-console, you will have to press `i` first, than you will be able to enter your text at the position of the cursor.

Next, you will have to press `ESC` to leave the input menu. To save your changes, type `:wq` (write & quit, the colon is to enter the command-mode), then hit `ENTER`.

Please have a look at the [help files](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html).

Comment: This isnt my question though. I can insert text, I need to know how to save it to be the commit message.

Comment: Sorry, added this in the answer. Use `:wq` and `ENTER`.

Comment: `:wq`+`ENTER` gives `E32: No file name`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't pass in the `-m` parameter into `git commit` then by default Git will open vim to allow the user to write the commit message.

To change the editor to something different run the following command (eg. for vim);

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

Comment: OP specifically requests Vim. Answer intentionally substitutes Vim for Emacs. *Editor war intensifies.*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the `-m` flag, then the editor will be opened. By default, it's vim but you can change it:

```
git config --global core.editor nano
```